# Java Netbeans: How to layer panels on top of each other?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, panels

Please bear with me as I've just started using NetBeans for the first time! Basically what I'm trying to do is create different panels that fit inside one frame, except that only one panel will be visible at a time. It'll start with one panel, and depending on what the user inputs, the panel that corresponds to what the user puts in pops up.

I've tried looking into utilizing LayeredPanes since that's what I've come after hours of researching this only.. I don't understand how to do it! I think using different panels would be much easier than using different frames, so that's why I'm just going to stick with layering panels.

If anyone could explain LayeredPanes, I'd be very grateful! I'm not sure my coding will help here, but if anyone needs it I'll put it up.

Comment: have you come across this tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Comment: You can learn LayeredPane fron Java's tutorial here: [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

As looking to your requirement this might be not right choice (IMO). What you can do is just add and remove panels from frame. This way you will not require layered panes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) tutorial should point you in the right direction, however, if you want to have items positioned over each other, you might also want to take a look at the [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html):

> The CardLayout class manages two or more components (usually JPanel
>   instances) that share the same display space.

Comment: Yes, this is likely the simplest way to do it. If you want a nice implementation of a user interface, try using `JTabbedPanes` and learning [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I dont think that what you need is a `LayeredPane`,

> *Basically what I'm trying to do is create different panels that fit inside one frame, except that only one panel will be visible at a time.*

Tell exactly what you want to achieve, I mean on what you are working on.

> *...and depending on what the user inputs, the panel that corresponds to what the user puts in pops up.*

I'd like to suggest a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) , show dialogs depending on the user inputs. To make sure if this is what you need, you want to provide us with more information. :)